# C++ How to use another (user-defined) class as an argument in a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments

I can't seem to find this anywhere exactly so hopefully it hasn't been asked before. I'm re-learning c++ and wanted to try to solve a problem I encountered last time but couldn't solve; making 2 complex classes (cartesian and polar) that have constructors with arguments of each other. The problem I have is that the first class doesn't seem to recognise the the second class exists, and such I can't use it in the constructor.

A stripped down version of my code:

```
class complex_ab{
friend class complex_rt;

public:
    complex_ab(): a(0), b(0) { }
    complex_ab(const double x, const double y): a(x), b(y) { }
    complex_ab(complex_rt);
    ~complex_ab() { }

private:
    double a, b;
};

class complex_rt{
    friend class complex_ab;
public:
    complex_rt(): r(0), theta(0) { }
    complex_rt(const double x, const double y): r(x), theta(y) { }
    complex_rt(complex_ab);
    ~complex_rt() { }

private:
    double r, theta;
};
```

and .cpp file

```
#include "complex.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

complex_ab::complex_ab(complex_rt polar){
    a = polar.r * cos(polar.theta);
    b = polar.r * sin(polar.theta);
}
complex_rt::complex_rt(complex_ab cart){
    r = sqrt(cart.a * cart.a + cart.b * cart.b);
    theta = atan(cart.b/cart.a);
}
```

The main file currently just returns 0 while I try to get this to compile. The errors I get are

```
error: field 'complex_rt' has incomplete type 'complex_ab'
  complex_ab(complex_rt);
                       ^
note: definition of 'class complex_ab' is not complete until the closing brace
 class complex_ab{
```

which I get twice for some reason, and then

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 complex_ab::complex_ab(complex_rt polar){
                       ^
```

I know it would probably be better to try and do it all in one class but this will bug me if I leave it unsolved, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any problem here, except the possibility that you posted stripped version of your code.

Comment: @Ajay by stripped down I just removed overloaded operator declarations that didn't have anything to do with the issue, the error messages came from this exact code (with other parts commented out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to explicitly forward-declare `complex_rt`, as `friend` declaration seems not to do it:

```
class complex_rt;

class complex_ab{
friend class complex_rt;
...
```

Full example: http://ideone.com/Q8GkQh

Comment: If that is true, template meta programming won't work at all.

Comment: @Ajay, hm, indeed. It turns out that all he needs is forward declaration. Changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks that's worked perfectly, I can see why it works I just never considered declaring classes before defining them like functions.